# RegEx:Grabbing a specific value between quotation marks

Tags: regex

I have a value like this:

```
"cat"  "car"  "cry"  "cruise"   "q":"222"
```

What regex will return the only the value 222 in this case?!
Note the value"222" is randomly generated each time, as the rest are constants.

I have attempted this:

```
"([^"]*)"
```

but it would return all the values between "" not a specific value.

Comment: What have you attempted so far? What **language** as well?

Comment: I have attempted this "([^"]*)" but it would return all the values between "" not a specific value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the colon exists as in your example, you can use the following regex:

```
:"([^"]+)"
```

Otherwise, be **greedy** and eat up all characters until the last occurrence:

```
.*"([^"]+)"
```

Comment: Yes the colon does exist. Thank you for the answer it worked just fine :)